# Displaying JSTL SQL value in webpage

Tags: sql, jstl

I have query like this

```
<sql:query dataSource="${data}" var="mn">  
SELECT MONTHNAME( DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -4 MONTH ) ) as Name ;
</sql:query>
```

getting output like this

### Name

october

I want to display this value in web page

I tried like this

```
    <c:set var="monthname" value="${mn}" />
    <b><font color="black"><c:out value="${monthname}" /></font></b>
```

but geeting output as :
 org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl@197074b

can anyone help me to display?

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable `mn` is [`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result.html).

You can display your result like this:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${mn.rows}">
   <c:out value="${row.Name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```